# Setting up separate repositories for backend/frontend on heroku/github

Tags: django, git, heroku

I am a bit new to heroku and git, but here goes.

I was advised to separate my static files permissions from my backend code permissions. This being the case, I could give designers free reign over making changes to front end stuff without worrying about doing any damage to any other backend code and I could give access to the back end people who need it separately.

What exactly is the best way to do this? How do I even facilitate something like this? I am running a django project on heroku currently.

PS: although the static folder lives in a separate area, I also have a template folders running along side some apps. I don't know if this will complicate things or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git, other than splitting repositories, which will significantly complicate your deployment process, there's no way to have custom permissions.